# Unable to upgrade redis-py package on ubuntu

Tags: python, redis, pip, ubuntu-14.04

Got successful message while installing but still unable to import package !

```
 (testme)ubuntu@msg:~$ sudo pip install redis==2.10.3
Downloading/unpacking redis==2.10.3
  Downloading redis-2.10.3.tar.gz (86Kb): 86Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package redis

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '__pycache__'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
Installing collected packages: redis
  Found existing installation: redis 2.9.1
    Uninstalling redis:
      Successfully uninstalled redis
  Running setup.py install for redis

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '__pycache__'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
Successfully installed redis
Cleaning up...
```

1.

```
(testme)ubuntu@msg:~$ pip freeze | grep redis
(testme)ubuntu@msg:~$
```

2.

```
(testme)ubuntu@msg:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import redis
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named redis
>>>
```

I also tried uninstall and then install but found no luck

Comment: Can someone tell me steps to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was doing `sudo pip install redis==2.10.3` while there was already same package installation outside virtualenv. So removed the package from outside the virtualenv and it worked.